# Match SMALLMONEY using % wildcard

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have write this code in SQL :

```
alter proc verfinanfiltrado(@valor smallmoney) as
select idconta,vencimento,historico,original,formpagto,planoconta,clifor
from financeiro where original like @valor
```

this procedure works , i want to write something like :

```
alter proc verfinanfiltrado(@valor smallmoney) as
select idconta,vencimento,historico,original,formpagto,planoconta,clifor
from financeiro where original like  % @valor %
```

example the procedure work with 746.06 but i want to show all the values that begins with 746 , like 746.06, 746.10, 748.12

And in the case of nvarchar ??

```
 alter proc verfinanfiltrado(@histo smallmoney) as
select idconta,vencimento,historico,original,formpagto,planoconta,clifor
from financeiro where historico  like  % @histo %
```

Comment: % and * are string functions, smallmoney appears to be numeric data.  So you would need to use between, >, <, <=, >= when working with numbers. `where round(original,0,1) = round(@valor,0,1)` for example

Comment: This work perfect for me , i only to solve when is nvarchar

Answer (score 2):

Converting the column (via string conversion or rounding) will prevent the use of indexes.  Don't do it.  Instead...

```
from financeiro where @value <= original and original < @value + 1
```

Comment: if value isn't a whole number wouldn't you get 747 when value is 746?  Say if value is 746.11 and data contains 747.10?

Comment: So?  handle it before you wake up the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE original >= ROUND(@valor,0,1) AND original < ROUND(@valor,0,1) + 1
```

Incidentally, xQberts solution in the comments to the original problem will work too, but this is sargable, so you'll benefit from any indecies on original

Answer (score 0):

I have solve with this proc

```
alter proc vencevalor (@valor smallmoney)as
select idconta,vencimento,pagamento,historico,original,formpagto,planoconta,clifor
from financeiro where round(original,0,1) = round (@valor,0,1)  
order by idconta desc
```

thanks to all